# How to extract data from previous 2 years based on particular date in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, forecasting

I have a csv file consisting of last 3 years of timeseries monthly data. Based on today's date, I would like to read only the previous 2 years of data for forecasting the future.

```
Data file example (has data from 01-01-15 to 31-10-19):  

    Date,Value
    01-01-17,2   
    01-02-17,5   
    01-03-17,8     
    01-04-17,4  
    01-05-17,2  
    01-06-17,9  
    01-07-17,8  
    01-08-17,7  
    01-09-17,5  
    01-10-17,1  
    01-11-17,2  
    01-12-17,3  
    01-01-18,5  
    01-02-18,6  
    01-03-18,8  
    01-04-18,2  
    01-05-18,5   
    01-06-18,6
```

Desired result:
If today's date is 01/01/19, I want my training data to be data from 01/01/17 - 31/12/18.

I tried:
`df[df['date'] > (pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d') - relativedelta(years = 2))]`

However, I am getting data from 01-01-17 to 31-10-19(last record) instead of from 01-01-17 to 31-12-18.

Comment: have you looked into using pandas?

Comment: @yalpsideman, yes I tried using pandas and datetime, but I am yet to figure out a way. I am a beginner in python..

Comment: Please show the code you currently have and ask a specific question about a problem you are unable to solve. The way the question is formulated right now, it looks like you are just asking for someone to do your task. That is off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: @zvone, I understand if it appears that way. But I am not able to solve it. Hence, asking for someone's help. It is okay if you don't want to.

Comment: @Vam96 Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```py
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> df[df.Date > datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=2)]
         Date  Value
12 2018-01-01      5
13 2018-01-02      6
14 2018-01-03      8
15 2018-01-04      2
16 2018-01-05      5
17 2018-01-06      6
```

**Update**

```py
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> from datetime import date

>>> start_date = pd.Timestamp(datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=2))
>>> end_date = pd.Timestamp(date(date.today().year-1, 12, 31))

>>> df[(df.Date >= start_date) & (df.Date <= end_date)]
```

---

```
         Date  Value
12 2018-01-01      5
13 2018-01-02      6
14 2018-01-03      8
15 2018-01-04      2
16 2018-01-05      5
17 2018-01-06      6
```

Comment: I tried:
df[df['date'] > (pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d') - relativedelta(years = 2))]

However, I am getting data from 01-01-17 to 31-10-19(last record) instead of from 01-01-17 to 31-12-18.