# Cut dataframe using start and end date with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a daily account of stock prices for a certain stock.

The dataframe starts in 2014, and ends this past week.

```
>>>df
0     2014-11-19  188.479996  187.369995  188.250000  188.169998  1880800.0   
1     2014-11-20  188.639999  187.289993  187.289993  188.509995   866800.0   
2     2014-11-21  190.479996  188.949997  190.429993  189.570007  1586200.0   
3     2014-11-24  190.210007  189.770004  190.020004  190.059998  1365900.0   
4     2014-11-25  190.559998  189.660004  190.339996  190.000000  1736700.0   
...          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...   
1507  2020-11-13  329.730011  325.890015  326.450012  329.010010  1996100.0   
1508  2020-11-16  333.119995  330.410004  331.649994  333.000000  3018800.0   
1509  2020-11-17  332.500000  329.250000  330.730011  331.339996  3052100.0   
1510  2020-11-18  332.140015  327.290009  331.630005  327.320007  2634900.0   
1511  2020-11-19  329.089996  325.429993  326.760010  328.709991  2962161.0
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe, df1, that only includes data from the past 2 years. How would I use datetime to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491093/how-to-extract-data-from-previous-2-years-based-on-particular-date-in-python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract data from previous 2 years based on particular date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491093/how-to-extract-data-from-previous-2-years-based-on-particular-date-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use date time to find today's date and then filter your df based on anything within the past two years:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# example data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-11-10', '2020-11-11', '2019-11-01', '2018-11-01', '2017-11-01'],
                   'vals': [1,2,3,4,5]}) 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# get today's date
today = datetime.datetime.today() 

# filter records within last two years of today
df[(today - df.date).dt.days <= 365*2]
```

Comment: This worked thank you. I accepted it as answered. Would you mind upvoting the initial question?